# How can I manually assign values to a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am learning about 2D arrays but I am stuck on this issue and I don't know what I am doing wrong. 
I have this so far:

```
    double[][] arr = new double[3][2];

    arr[0] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0}; // this doesn't work
```

but that seems to be wrong for some reason, I get

```
 Array Initializer is not allowed here
```

what I am trying to do is make the first column of the first row equal to:
1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0

I can do it by declaring another array and then setting it equal to the first column of the first row:

```
    double [] arr1 = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
    double[][] arr = new double[3][2];

    arr[0] = arr1; // this seems to work
```

My question is how can I add the values manually without having to first declare an array and setting it equal to it, or without having to use a `for` loop.

edit: The answers of the the previous questions were too complicated for me to understand. 
Thanks for the answers guys, this helped me a lot.

Comment: @MadProgrammer References.

Comment: Use `arr[0] = new double[] {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};`

Comment: There's also no point to declare the array as `double[][] arr = new double[3][2];`, just use `double[][] arr = new double[3][];`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm sorry, it's very early in the morning, so I might have missed what you were trying to say?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't want to be too explicit :p. The `new double[3][2]` is creating an array of 3 array references to 3 arrays of size 2. Nothing prevents you from reassigning one of those to an array of a difference size.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Okay, that just freaks the crap out me :P - It's probably very logical and or, but my morning brain just didn't need that right now